# How get time server in firebase by kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want put time server to database firebase by kotlin
I want to get the time like that : 1546513134

```
val timestamp = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
ref.child("Users").setValue(timestamp)
```

I get it on score =  {.sv: "timestamp"} ..

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue) describes `ServerType.TIMESTAMP` as..

> A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase Database servers.

Since it is just a placeholder when you set value as `ServerType.TIMESTAMP`, it converts automatically to a timestamp.

Here is my test code.

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("test/timestamp")
            .setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,(error, ref) -> {

                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue()); // Prints 1539230166407
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            });
```